# Странное поведение при сложении строк

Tags: python

Почему при сложении `'1' + '2'` результат `'12'`?

Comment: А почему вы ожидаете что-то другое? Это ж строки, а не числа.

Comment: Это логичное поведение: складываем строки - строки сцепляются, складываем числа - числа складываются. Если строки в зависимости от содержимого будут иногда сцепляться, иногда складываться как числа - это будет хаос.

Answer (score 1):

Питон не приводит типы. В данном случае вы производите операцию сложения над строкой (cоединение).

Так же обращаю ваще внимание что произойдет ошибка в случае сложения `int` и `str` типов.

Например:

```
'1' + 2
```

или

```
2 + '1'
```

А чтобы получить результат арифметического сложения нужно сделать так:

```
int('1') + int('2')
```

Comment: Или так: ```sum(map(int, ['1', '2']))```

Answer (score 0):

"Сложение" строк правильнее называть конкатенация. Такое поведение покажется вам логичнее, если вы замените `1` и `2` на, допустим `а` и `б`:

```py
'a' + 'б'    # Результатом будет 'aб'
```

1 и 2 в вашем примере - это точно такие же символы, как и буквы.

Операторы типа `+`, `-`, `*` и т.п. для разных *типов данных* в Python будут иметь разное значение. Это явление называется *полиморфизмом*.

Для пользовательских типов данных вы сможете переопределить это поведение самостоятельно. Для этого нужно переопределить т.н. магические методы, которые на самом деле вызываются, когда вы используете операторы. Например, когда вы складываете что-то с помощью оператора `+`, на самом деле вы вызываете метод `__add__`:

```py
x = '1'
y = '2'
x.__add__(y)  # Результат будет '12', т.к. это одно и то же, что и x + y
```